# Execute Powershell commands in vb.net

Tags: powershell

I need to create a gui with vb.net as vm extended switch acl. the powershell snippet is

```
add-VMNetworkAdapterExtendedAcl -computername "Ati-PC" -Vmname "Windows7"
    -action deny -diretion inbound -remoteport "80" -protocol "TCP" -weight 10
    -LocalIPAddress "ANY" -RemoteIPAddress "ANY" -LocalPort "ANY" RemotePort "80"
```

The VB code I wrote for "Create" button is

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click
    Dim runSpace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()
    runSpace.Open()
    Dim pipeLine As Pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline()
    Dim ExtendedACL As New Command("Add-VMNetworkAdapterExtendedACL")
     ExtendedACL.Parameters.Add("vmname", txtVMName.Text)
    ExtendedACL.Parameters.Add("ComputerName", txtPhySvr.Text)
    ExtendedACL.Parameters.Add("Action", cmbAction.Text)
    ExtendedACL.Parameters.Add("Direction", cmbDirection.Text)
    ExtendedACL.Parameters.Add("Protocol", cmbProtocol.Text)
    ExtendedACL.Parameters.Add("LocalIPAddress", txtLocalIP.Text)
    ExtendedACL.Parameters.Add("RemoteIPAdddress", txtRemoteIP.Text)
    ExtendedACL.Parameters.Add("LocalPort", txtLocalPort.Text)
    ExtendedACL.Parameters.Add("RemotePort", txtRemotePort.Text)
    ExtendedACL.Parameters.Add("weight", txtWeight.Text)
    pipeLine.Commands.Add(ExtendedACL)
    Dim vNameProcesses As Collection(Of PSObject) = pipeLine.Invoke()

    Dim psObject As PSObject
    For Each psObject In vNameProcesses
        Dim process As Process = TryCast(psObject.BaseObject, Process)
    Next

End Sub
```

However this code shoot an exception. Can someone help me to find the issue ?

Regards
Gayan

Comment: What exception? Where?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. "this code shoots an exception" is meaningless without the information about *what exception was thrown*. You have that information right in front of you, so there's absolutely no reason you should not provide that information to us. If you want help here, you need to be **specific**, and provide the details you already have. You're asking us for free help to solve **your** problem, so it's in your best interest to make it as easy as possible to help you. Please [edit] your question and provide the additional details. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry experts. It was typo. The Parameter of line 12 should be RemoteIPAddress not "RemoteIPAdddress". Feels guilty...:-(